# Model view controller architecture - sample code

Tags: cocoa, model, view, controller

I am studying the model view controller architecture and want to apply the same in a small project in cocoa. However, i do not get the right approach and study material to achieve this. I mean how do i design a class for model controller, view controller and window controller. Can u please direct me to some sample code, which applies the MVC architecture?  Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple provide a couple of useful documents for beginners:

- [Cocoa Application Tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCTutorial)
- [Cocoa Fundamentals Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/)

Comment: Thanks so much for the links!! Helped a lot... :)

Comment: They're all good, but an updated link is: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/Introduction/Introduction.html